# it doesnt go through all the cell, sometimes jump to another one without going in a sequel

Tags: excel, vba, cells

```
Sub Vecinas()


    For Each cell In [Data!A2.A50001]

        pmNoVecias = cell.Offset(0, 0)
        pmNameOrigen = cell.Offset(0, 1)
        pmNameVecina = cell.Offset(0, 7)
        pmVecinas = cell.Offset(0, 8)
        pmIntentos = cell.Offset(0, 9)


        If pmNameOrigen = "" Then
           Exit For
        End If

        If pmVecinas = "Yes" Then

            If pmIntentos < 100 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("Borrar").Select
                cell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial
                Sheets("Data").Select
                cell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Else

            If pmIntentos > 100 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("Agregar").Select
                cell.EntireRow.Insert
                Sheets("Data").Select
                cell.EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                cell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

This program runs fine, it deletes information from one sheet and puts it in another one, the only problem is that it doesn't go through every single cell, sometimes jump 2 or 3. How can I make for this program to go to every single cell?

Answer (score 0):

When a row is deleted, the row under it is not inspected, but skipped.
Eg. if you delete row 2, row 3 becomes the new row 2; but your For each loop goes on, to row 3. This means one row got skipped.
You can try using cell.EntireRow.Clear instead of Delete, and after the code is finished, just sort your table, or select blank cells in a column and delete rows.